# how to get Message text from this Firebase Cloud Messaging unity C#?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, messaging

[look to the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN0vH.png)how to get Message text from this Firebase Cloud Messaging unity C# this is my code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class pushfirebase : MonoBehaviour {

    public void Start() {
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
        Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    }

    public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received Registration Token: " + token.Token);
    }

    public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.From);}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OnMessageReceived` method, you can access the message body like so:

```
e.Message.Notification.Body
```

You may need to be a little bit careful though because the `Notification` object won't always be present. So check to make sure it isn't `null` before you use it.